# Variable inside echo <a> tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do I echo a variable inside the  tag? this code does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
echo "<a href='productdetails.php?image="$results['image']"'><img src='images/".$results["image"]."' class='img-responsive' /></a><br />";
```

Comment: are you sure `$results["image"]` that image key has a value ?

Comment: First quick thing I see is you are not concatenating here - `image="$results`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this

```
echo "<a href='productdetails.php?image="{$results['image']}"'>
    <img src='images/{$results["image"]}' class='img-responsive' />
</a><br />";
```

Or

```
echo "<a href='productdetails.php?image=$results[image]'>
    <img src='images/$results[image]' class='img-responsive' />
</a><br />";
```

Or like your original but with the correct concatenation

```
echo "<a href='productdetails.php?image=" . $results['image'] . "'>
        <img src='images/".$results["image"]."' class='img-responsive' />
    </a><br />";
```

Comment: I didn't know you can do this even without using `.`. New knowledge acquired.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful post! I missed out the concatenation

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this, you missed `.` before and after `$results['image']`, so proper concatenation is not happening:

```
echo "<a href='productdetails.php?image=" . $results['image'] . "'><img src='images/" . $results["image"] . "' class='img-responsive' /></a><br />";
```

Method 2:
Take it in a variable:

```
$image = $results['image'];
echo "<a href='productdetails.php?image=" . $image . "'><img src='images/" . $image . "' class='img-responsive' /></a><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
echo 
    '<a href="productdetails.php?image=' . $results['image'] . '">
        <img src="images/' . $results['image'] . '" class="img-responsive" />
    </a><br />';
```